# "konzentrieren" as reflexive verb?

Tags: verb, reflexive

I want to say

> The conference focuses on global warming.

Should I say

> (a) Die Konferenz konzentriert auf die globale Erwärmung
>
> (b) Die Konferenz konzentriert sich auf die globale Erwärmung

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The verb konzentrieren is usually used reflexively:

> Ich konzentriere mich (auf etwas)
>   Du konzentrierst dich …
>   Er konzentriert sich …

Also in your case, the conference is concentrating on something:

> Die Konferenz konzentriert sich auf die globale Erwärmung.

On a side note, konzentrieren is usually reserved for humans, so I would suggest using "beschäftigt sich (hauptsächlich) mit …" in this case.

Comment: `sich auf etwas konzentrieren` is only reserved for *sentient* beings if in the broader sense of `thinking about something`. You could also say `Der Löwe konzentriert sich bei der Jagd auf die kranken Beutetiere.` or `Die Fehler im Text konzentrieren sich auf die Verben.`

Comment: There is also a non-reflexive use of _konzentrieren_ in the sense of increasing the proportion of some substance, e.g. _Saft konzentrieren_ or _Salzsäure konzentrieren_.

Answer (score 3):

Die Konferenz "konzentriert sich" auf ...
That is no German. That is a word-for-word translation of Englisch "focuses on".

You can express the idea with: Hauptthema der Konferenz ist die Klimaerwärmung.
Or: Die Konferenz beschäftigt sich hauptsächlich/vornehmlich/ausschließlich mit
dem Thema Klimaerwärmung.

Konzentrier dich! - That is what you say to a pupil who hasn't his mind on the task.

Comment: Die Behauptung scheint mir verwegen. Dass sich z. B. Truppenteile irgendwo konzentrieren (eine durchaus gebräuchliche Wendung), bedeutet eine räumliche Verdichtung. Die Übertragung auf eine gedankliche Verdichtung liegt ziemlich nahe und taucht auch schon in Tolstoj-Übersetzungen von vor 1920 auf. So sehr mir sinnarme Übertragungen aus dem Englischen zuwider sind - hier erkenne ich keine.